# Verify read-only fields using cypress

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, cypress

I have a few text fields which when I login as a specific user (rights of a read only) , all the text fields are not allowed to be edited.
I am trying to automate this page in Cypress.

I tried using :

```
cy.get(element).should("be.disabled") 
cy.get(element).should("have.text", readonly,readonly).
```

Both failed.

Please let me know if anyone has any other options.

Comment: What's the actual DOM you're trying to test? _Are_ the inputs disabled? Do they have the _attribute_ `readonly` set (is that what you're trying to test with `"have.text"`)? Something else (e.g. code behind just ignores whatever the user tries to type in)?

Comment: The DOM is an input field (a text box) . They dont have an attribute "readonly" . Currently there is no value in the text boxes,

Comment: Can you paste the relevant DOM? Disabling can be implemented in many ways - your code should be align with the specific way.

Comment: Here is one example of it. there are 15 text fields . all of them are non editable.

Comment: Past the ACTUAL dom from view page source so we can see the input field, any label field and any other wrappers immediately around them. We can guess endlessly about what it might be but you can tell us (and then we can help you) by showing us the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the next code:

```
cy.get(element).should('have.attr', 'readonly', 'readonly')
```